# How to aggregate and sum items by month?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes (orders and items with prices):

```
orders = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2], 'sum_delivery': [10, 0], 'date': ['2016-01-01', '2016-01-05']})
items = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3], 'order_id': [1,1,2], 'price': [100, 100, 500], 'count':[5,5,1]})
```

I want to aggregate data by month and get this dataframe in the end:

```
{'date': ['2016-01'], 'sum': [1510]}
```

It is possible with sql very easy, but how to do it with pandas?

Comment: How is the aggregation taking place? Could you demonstrate it with an example?

Comment: If it's so easy with SQL, why don't you post your SQL and we can try to translate it into pandas syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to take `sum_delivery` into account only once per order, so you have to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) before you join:

```
>>> items2 = items.groupby('order_id', as_index=False)['sum'].sum()
>>> items2
   order_id   sum
0         1  1000
1         2   500
```

Now you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) to use custom column names:

```
>>> res = pd.merge(orders, items2, left_on = 'id', right_on = 'order_id')[['date', 'sum', 'sum_delivery']]
>>> res
         date   sum  sum_delivery
0  2016-01-01  1000            10
1  2016-01-05   500             0
```

And now just do simple math and simple [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) (don't forget to use `as_index=False`):

```
>>> res['date'] = res['date'].str[:7]
>>> res['sum2'] = res['sum'] + res['sum_delivery']
>>> res2 = res.groupby('date', as_index=False)['sum2'].sum()
>>> res2
      date  sum2
0  2016-01  1510
```

Comment: Hey! this res['date'] = res['date'].str[:7] -- is a cheat )

Comment: kind of. Well you can easily adjust this piece of code to cope with `datetime`, I thought that strings just will make code shorter and it's not the point here :)

Comment: something like `res.date = res.date.dt.year * 1000 + res.date.dt.month` would do the trick :)

Comment: Ok, thanks I understand the idea, but is it possible to do this task a bit shorter? Maybe pivot_table could help?

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it works:

```
items2 = items.groupby('order_id', as_index=False)['sum'].sum()
res = pd.merge(orders, items2, left_on = 'id', right_on = 'order_id')[['date', 'sum', 'sum_delivery']]

res['sum2'] = res['sum'] + res['sum_delivery']
res.index = pd.to_datetime(res.date)
tmpdf = res.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("M")).sum()[['sum2']]
```