# Total sum amount per month using date time in Python

Tags: python, list, datetime, sum

Now I have a list of dates and values, but I don't know how to do calculations with the date structure.

It looks like

```
[[datetime.date(2018, 8, 10) 1076.2392505636847]
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 11) 3537.9781979862732]
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 12) 8637.536518161462]
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 13) 15660.768121458246]
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 14) 21087.477911830327]
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 15) 21087.477911830327]
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 16) 15660.768121458246]
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 17) 8637.536518161465]
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 18) 3537.9781979862732]
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 19) 1076.2392505636856]]
```

also, I know that

```
startdate = datetime.date(2018, 8, 10)
enddate = datetime.date(2018,8, 19)
```

I want to create another list that consists of ['Year-Month' data, total sum of the month]. In this case, it will be just ['2018-8' total sum]. if enddate is like 2020,8,19, then the length would be 25 (two years and a month).

Could you share some useful functions/approaches that I may use?

Comment: can you assume that you list is sorted by dates?

Comment: So you want to aggregate by month. Are you able to use pandas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### collections.defaultdict

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for an O(n) solution which does not require sorting.

```
import datetime

L = [[datetime.date(2018, 8, 10), 1076.23], [datetime.date(2018, 8, 11), 3537.97],
     [datetime.date(2018, 8, 19), 1076.23], [datetime.date(2018, 9, 10), 5.23],
     [datetime.date(2018, 9, 11), 10.97], [datetime.date(2018, 10, 19), 15.23]]

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

for date, val in L:
    d[date.strftime('%Y-%m')] += val

# defaultdict(int,
#             {'2018-08': 5690.43,
#              '2018-09': 16.20,
#              '2018-10': 15.23})

res = list(map(list, d.items()))

print(res)

[['2018-08', 5690.43],
 ['2018-09', 16.20],
 ['2018-10', 15.23]]
```

#### pandas

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, you can use Pandas:

```
# construct dataframe from list of lists
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['date', 'val'])

# convert to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# perform GroupBy operation over monthly frequency
res = df.set_index('date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))['val'].sum().reset_index()

print(res)

        date      val
0 2018-08-31 5690.430
1 2018-09-30   16.200
2 2018-10-31   15.230
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have some questions about the code,
d[date.strftime('%Y-%m')] += val -> so this means that you only collect date information of year and month and put them into d, by adding up val ?
res = list(map(list, d.items()))  -> what does this do?

Comment: Yes, the `defaultdict` key only refers to year and month. `list(map(list, d.items()))` takes each dictionary item (key-value pair), converts it to a list one-at-a-time (hence `map`), then passes it to a `list`. So you end up with a list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min` and `max` to find starttime and endtime. Then use `itertools.groupby` to group the entries for each month and find sum for each group

```
lst = [[datetime.date(2018, 8, 10), 1076.2392505636847],
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 11), 3537.9781979862732],
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 12), 8637.536518161462],
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 13), 15660.768121458246],
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 14), 21087.477911830327],
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 15), 21087.477911830327],
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 16), 15660.768121458246],
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 17), 8637.536518161465],
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 18), 3537.9781979862732],
 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 19), 1076.2392505636856]]

starttime = min(lst)
endtime   = max(lst)

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
res = [[k.strftime('%Y-%m'), sum(map(itemgetter(1), group))] for k,group in groupby(lst, lambda sl: sl[0].replace(day=1))]
print (starttime, endtime)
print (res)
```

**Output**

```
[datetime.date(2018, 8, 10), 1076.2392505636847] [datetime.date(2018, 8, 19), 1076.2392505636856]
[['2018-08', 99999.99999999999]]
```

Answer (score 1):

With Pandas it would be more intuitive and easy to understand

Load your data in your data frame

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[datetime.date(2018, 8, 10), 1076.2392505636847],
                 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 11), 3537.9781979862732],
                 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 12), 8637.536518161462],
                 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 13), 15660.768121458246],
                 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 14), 21087.477911830327],
                 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 15), 21087.477911830327],
                 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 16), 15660.768121458246],
                 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 17), 8637.536518161465],
                 [datetime.date(2018, 8, 18), 3537.9781979862732],
                 [datetime.date(2019, 8, 19), 1076.2392505636856]], 
                 columns=["Date",'amount'])
```

Convert the date column to datetime

```
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

Create index on year and month

```
df.index=[df.Date.dt.year, df.Date.dt.month]
```

Aggregate on year and month

```
df.groupby(['year','month']).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you should try Panda
you can check [here](https://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/) for an intro or 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821161/how-to-aggregate-and-sum-items-by-month) for a similar discussion

Comment: Please see why [link-only answers are discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). The question already has a pandas (not panda) answer tailored to the problem.